# When to use php microframeworks?

Tags: php, frameworks, coding-style

I am not sure if the question fits SO's guidelines, but I would like to know if there is a specific situation where I can use micro-frameworks. Going by the nomenclature, it's suitable for small projects. But we can never tell if a project, which is small in nature at the moments, won't grow large later. Does this mean we can use micro-frameworks only for REST APIs and stuff (which are almost always smaller part of a large project) ?

Comment: It seems that you wouldn't want to use a separate framework for an API because that would likely isolate it from the majority of the project making it harder to develop and keep in sync. Microframeworks, in general terms, can grow; they are dubbed as such because they contain fewer inbuilt components and mechanisms, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends mostly on your needs. If I want to create something that takes few hours and it's more or less just "Hello world" with some spice, I use [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/). If I need something even slightly bigger, I grab [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/) and spend next hour configuring it (just because it's probably worth spending more time on it). But it'd be naive to think it's as simple. I know people that roll bigger frameworks even for the tiniest projects, just because they can one day grow. Other people do them in micro-frameworks and just rewrite them if they need to. Just sit with your team and write down pros and cons of using micro-framework in given situation, that should work the best.

Comment: "...for the tiniest projects, just because they can one day grow." My only concern is whether I can grow a project while using microframeworks, and with minimal coding.